# Hbase Master and Region servers could not be started

Tags: apache, hadoop, hbase, cluster-computing, apache-zookeeper

Hadoop is successfully running in distributed mode.

Getting following error while starting HBase in distributed mode.

Tried everything in hbase-site.xml configuration. No idea how to proceed with the problem?

> ```
> 014-03-10 13:55:42,493 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server ip-112-11-1-111.ec2.internal/112.11.1.111:2181. 
> Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (Unable to locate a login configuration)
>
> 2014-03-10 13:55:42,494 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
>
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>         at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
>         at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:599)
>         at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
>         at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)
> 2014-03-10 13:55:42,594 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
> 2014-03-10 13:55:42,594 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 3 retries
> 2014-03-10 13:55:42,595 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine: Failed to start master
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:2104)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:152)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:104)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:76)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2118)
> Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
>         at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
>         at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
>         at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1041)
>         at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1069)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:199)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.createAndFailSilent(ZKUtil.java:1109)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.createAndFailSilent(ZKUtil.java:1099)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.createAndFailSilent(ZKUtil.java:1083)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.createBaseZNodes(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:162)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:155)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.<init>(HMaster.java:345)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:2099)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that ZooKeeper is provisioned and running expectedly.
2. Check `zoo.cfg` and `/etc/hosts` to make sure that all zookeeper servers are reachable by the HBase master.